# Sorting a list of different values by a specific field

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

I've got a list of different types that I've read from a spreadsheet.

```
>>>data
[1.0, u'1', u'COMPLETED', u'TONGUE', 30.0, 1.0, '2014/01/28 09:33:16', 30.0, 210.0, u'1 CW', 0.0, 2.0, 210.0, u'H1490']
[1.0, u'1', u'COMPLETED', u'TONGUE', 30.0, 1.0, '04/02/2014 09:14:36', 30.0, 230.0, u'2 CCW', 0.0, 7.0, 210.0, u'H990']
.......
```

and I would like to be sorted by date, i.e. sorted by the 6th field (`data[1][6],data[2][6]`,etc...). How could I indicate Python to sort this list by field number 6?

Comment: pass key use a lambda to sorted or sort

Comment: @Owen a zipped list is nothing similar to what I am asking

Comment: This is very difficult without a consistent date format. Is "04/02/2014" later or earlier than "05/01/2014"? Depends on whether the latter is May 1st 2014 or the 5th of January 2014.

Comment: you are going to need to turn your date `str` into something that will sort correctly, like a `datetime`.  With inconsistent date format maybe look at `dateutil` parser.

Comment: @cmd What if I have all dates in the same format? %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S ? Strings could also be sorted right?

Comment: YYYYMMDD style dates can be sorted lexicographically, so in that case you don't need to do any parsing at all.

Comment: yes `str` can be sorted lexicographically as Kevin said, but if its not in most significant element order and each element `0` padded to the same number of digits, it will not turn out how you want.

Comment: @cmd Yes, I've noticed. I think I would have less control on sorting operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sorted` and specify that you want to sort by 6th field.

You can use `dateutil.parser` to parse the date:

```
import dateutil.parser
sorted(data, key=lambda x: dateutil.parser.parse(x[6]))
```

Or if you want to sort data in-place and do less look-ups:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
data.sort(key=lambda x: parse(x[6]))
```

Comment: @Ffisegydd then write your own function that returns comparable date for your string and use it as a key.

Comment: @Ffisegydd  I've updated my answer based on your comments.  Thanks!

Comment: @jh314 That was useful. I could either use a parser or sort them lexicographically as @_Kevin said before

Comment: @Manolete  Glad to know it was useful!

Answer (score 1):

Use `sorted` using a  `lambda` as a key to sort and `dateutil`:

```
from dateutil import parser

sorted(data,key = lambda x:parser.parse(x[6]))
```

If you don't have dateutil installed:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

If you want to sort the list in place and avoid creating a new list:

```
data.sort(key=lambda x:parser.parse(x[6]))
```

If the dates are in one of two different formats you can use your own function:

```
def date_parse(x):
    date = None
    for form in ["%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S","%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"]:
        try:
            date = datetime.strptime(x,form)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return date

sorted(data,key = lambda x: date_parse(x[6]))
```